# Ruby: How to screen-scrape the result of an Ajax request

Tags: ruby, ajax, screen-scraping, open-uri

I have written a ruby script to screen scrape something using the 'open-uri' and 'hpricot' gems - everything works great so far.

But now I have to screen scrape something which is returned after a form is submitted via a javascript function (called by an 'onchange' event handler from a drop-down menu):

```
function submit_form() {
  document.list.action="/some/sort/of/path";
  document.list.submit();
}
```

AFAIK, open-uri lets you submit only GET requests. And if I'm not mistaken, a POST request would be needed here.

So my question is: what do I need to install and to 'require' and how would the ruby code then look like (to make that POST request) - sorry, I'm still pretty much of a n00b...

Thank you very much for your help!

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you definitely should use [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/). It provides a nifty interface to interact with remote pages, forms on them, and so forth ([see this example](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/blob/master/examples/flickr_upload.rb)).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just read the documentation - very good solution indeed! Plus, Mechanize integrates with Nokogiri.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby standard library has the [http class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html), which naturally supports the POST operation.

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://www.example.com/some/sort/of/path')
```

If you find the API there less than optimal, then take a look at the [httparty gem](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/)

Finally, while hpricot is a great gem, it isn't actively developed any longer. You should consider moving to [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) which practically replaces hpricot and improves upon it.

Comment: Thanks for your input - interesting!